# when vpn off how to detect in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vpn

```
import React from "react";
import { Offline, Online } from "react-detect-offline";
export default function DropDown() {
return (
    <>
    <Online>Only shown when you're online</Online>
    <Offline>Only shown offline (surprise!)</Offline>
    </>
  );
}
```

it is detecting only when we are in online/offline. so I want to add detect weather we off the vpn  connection its shows you are offline and when vpn on it detect you are online as well

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+detect+vpn+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Generally speaking a VPN is handled outside the scope of your fronted app. You may be able to retrieve the device's public ip and infer wether or not it is currently connected to the one vpn you know / where you know the public ip range.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're building some sort of an internal website which is supposed to be available only when you're connected to VPN. If that's the case, I'd suggest doing a 'ping' request to some internal resource. If it is not available, you'd display it as offline.

Simply perform a GET or even an OPTIONS http call, if it fails it means that you're off VPN. This is not an ideal way to detect VPN connection, but doing it in the browser another way would be difficult.

Comment: yes your assume is right, i just want that when vpn connection and offline its should shown offline msg, but when vpn on as well as online its should show msg you are online

Comment: Yes, exactly. Simply call some url that's only available when connected to VPN. If it is reachable and finishes with success, it means you're connected, otherwise you're not.